# Word for making people think you're crazy so they can't argue with you?

Tags: single-word-requests

I noticed today that you can't really argue with a three-year-old. Three-year-olds lack the experience and the facts.  On the other hand, when someone tries to argue with someone in a position of authority; someone who clearly has lots of experience and intelligence, simply due to the fact that they have been elected to such a high position; sometimes it feels about the same as arguing with the three-year-old.

Also, I remember working as a camp counselor many years ago, and one of the things we used to do as counselors was, if a kid asked when free time was, we would answer their question with a question; for instance:

> Kid: "When is free time?"
>   Counselor: "I don't know; when is free time?"

So this makes me wonder; is there a word for a person who fools someone into thinking that they are crazy, for purposes of saving the time of getting into an argument?

Comment: 'gaslighting' is related but for the other direction, making someone think they're crazy and so shouldn't bother trying to argue.

Comment: Is the person doing the fooling, fooling the second person into thinking the first person or the second person is the one that's crazy? In the 'arguing with a person in authority' example, are you comparing yourself or the person in authority to a three year old, or are you the person in authority?

Comment: It's known as 'feigning madness'.

Comment: Shakespeare called it Hamlet's "Antic Disposition"  -- shakespeare-online.com/plays/hamlet/antichamlet.html

Comment: Are you looking for a verb, an adjective, a noun? Please add an example sentence to clarify.

Comment: **Play dumb** [To pretend that one has no or little knowledge (of something); to act ignorant or uninformed about something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+dumb) If someone likes this suggestion they are free to post it. I am, unofficially, in semi-retirement. :>)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Semi-retirement?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh that's good!  That's prefect!  Thanks!

Comment: @WS2 yes, no longer posting answers or questions. But still popping in from time to time :)

Comment: You can also *feign ignorance*.  That is a bit less strong than *feign madness*.  *Play dumb* is excellent but quite informal -- so you wouldn't want to use it with the official who's playing dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is a bit different, "crazy like a fox" may be applicable? But I think that phrase may imply more malevolence than what you describe.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please make sure that when making suggestions you back them up with references, I have never heard of "crazy like a fox" and hence have no idea whether it's a good answer or not.